# How can I convert this sample code using promises to generator?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, generator, es6-promise

I am new to node.js and am working in Node v6.10. Most of my code on a project I recently started is written using promises, and queries `MongoDB` using `mongoose ODM` which is a promise based solution. Now, I have been reading up on async programming and  found out that generators provide cleaner code than Promises or callbacks, But I have been having trouble porting my code to Generators.

SO I was wondering if anyone can guide me how to do it?

Here is a sample code I want to convert:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

class GeneratorTest {
    testFn(number) {
        if(number % 2 === 0) {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
        return Promise.reject(new Error("Not Divisible by 2"));
    }
}

let obj = new GeneratorTest();

obj.testFn(Math.round(Math.random()*100))
.then(() => Math.round(Math.random()*100))
.then((res) => {
    if(res % 3 === 0) {
        return res;
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(new Error("Not Divisible by 3"));
    }
}).then((result) => {
    return "YES";
}).catch((reason) => {
    console.log(reason.message);
    return "NO";
});
```

Thanks!

**EDIT 1: Conversion Try using `co`**

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const co = require('co');

class GeneratorTest {
    testFn(number) {
        if(number % 2 === 0) {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
        return Promise.reject(new Error("Not Divisible by 2"));
    }
}

let obj = new GeneratorTest();

let result = obj.testFn(Math.random()*100);



co(function* (){try {
        let res = yield obj.testFn(Math.round(Math.random()*100))
        if(res % 3 === 0) {
            return res;
        } else {
            throw new Error("Not Divisible by 3");
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("IN CATCH");
        console.log(e)
    }});
```

But I get the error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Not Divisible by 2
    at GeneratorTest.testFn (/home/ayush/Desktop/generator-test/index.js:9:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ayush/Desktop/generator-test/index.js:15:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Comment: You can use `co` npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/co

Comment: Also take a look at [`async/await`](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9), which is an upcoming language feature for handling promises in a more "synchronous-looking" manner.

Comment: @robertklep yeah, but my runtime in AWS Lambda with nodejs 6.10, and async await come in 7.10

Comment: @AyushGupta true, it's more a general suggestion, as handling promises with generators is a bit of a hack, and `async/await` is an actual language construct (you can get `async/await` working on Node 6 as well, using a transpiler like Babel).

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

The question was updated so here's a quick update.
The unhandled rejection is caused by this line:

```
let result = obj.testFn(Math.random()*100);
```

where you clearly don't handle the rejection (and you're very unlikely to get a number that is both an integer and an even one at that) so the error is not surprising at all.

You can change:

```
console.log(e)
```

to:

```
console.log('Error:', e.message || e);
```

for less verbose output to see what's going on more clearly.

#### Original answer

First of all the code `if(number % 1 === 0)` contrary to your `"Not Divisible by 2"` message tests if the number is divisible by 1 (not by 2) and this is always true for any integer. It means that in the code that you included in your question it is impossible to get the `Not Divisible by 2` promise rejection (since you're using `Math.round` in your code) and the errors that you included must have been printed by some other code than the one that you included here.

This specific code is hard to convert while showing what's the difference (because you're ignoring the return values) but I'll give you some general example to show where the return values and exceptions come from and where they end up and how they relate to the promise resolution or rejection values.

When you have a function that returns a promise then normally you run it as:

```
f()
  .then((value) => {
    console.log('Value:', value);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error:', error);
  });
```

The `f()` function returns a promise that can be either rejected or resolved and the correct message will be printed.

With generator-based coroutines (like `co` or Bluebird.coroutine) it will be:

```
try {
  let value = yield f();
  console.log('Value:', value);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error:', error);
}
```

Here the `f()` function still returns the promise - it can be identical to `f()` in the previous example.

With async/await syntax of ES8 it will be:

```
try {
  let value = await f();
  console.log('Value:', value);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error:', error);
}
```

Keep in mind that the code using `yield` must be wrapped in a correct coroutine wrapper, like this:

```
co(function* () {
  // ...
});
```

or:

```
co.wrap(function* () {
  // ...
})();
```

or:

```
P.coroutine(function* () {
  // ...
});
```

(where `P` is the Bluebird's Promise) and the code that uses `await` must be inside a function declared with the `async` keyword:

```
(async () {
  // ...
})();
```

What's important is that all `async` function returns a promise, just like all of the functions returned by the coroutine wrappers (like `co.wrap` and `P.coroutine`). Any exception thrown in the body ends up as this promise rejection and any returned value resolves the promise.

Comment: But what if f() rejects a promise, where do I handle the rejection?

Comment: @AyushGupta you handle the rejection of `f()` in the `catch` block, like I did in my examples. The rejected promise is converted to a raised exception by the `await` operator (or in place of `yield` for generator-based coroutines).

Comment: it's not working though, my rejection from `TestFn` is not being caught in the catch block while the `Not divisible by 3` is

Comment: @AyushGupta the unhandled rejection is caused by this line: `let result = obj.testFn(Math.random()*100);` where you don't handle the rejection. Also you can change `console.log(e)` to `console.log(e.message)` or `console.log(e.message || e)` to have less verbose output to see clearly what's going on. That code works with `co`, it would work with `Bluebird.coroutine` and would work with `async` (if you changed `yield` to `await`).